# "DEPRECATION WARNING: Modifying already cached Relation" on Postgres MAX/GREATEST combination query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have groups and a group has many posts. A post has many post_likes, post_comments, and post_attachments. I am building a feed of group posts, and I would like to sort the posts based on activity. So, for a given group of posts, I want to show the posts in DESC chronological order based on when the posts were created, but also when the posts were most recently liked, commented on, or had an attachment added to them.

Here is the "feed" method in the group model:

```
def feed
  Post.unscoped.includes([:post_likes, :post_comments, :post_attachments]).
  joins("LEFT JOIN post_likes ON post_likes.post_id = posts.id").
  joins("LEFT JOIN post_comments ON post_comments.post_id = posts.id").
  joins("LEFT JOIN post_attachments ON post_attachments.post_id = posts.id").
  where("posts.group_id = ?", id).group("posts.id").order('MAX(GREATEST("posts"."created_at", "post_likes"."created_at", "post_comments"."created_at", "post_attachments"."created_at")) DESC')
end
```

I'm joining in the post_likes, post_comments, and post_attachments so that I have access to their `created_at` dates for sorting. I group by `posts.id` and add the `MAX` so that I get the most recent activity without any duplicate posts. That was working just fine, but then I upgraded to Rails 4.2 and now I am getting this deprecation warning:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: Modifying already cached Relation. The cache will be reset. Use a cloned Relation to prevent this warning
```

In my attempts to squelch that warning, it came down to removing the `MAX` declaration and the `group("posts.id")` from the query. The problem now though is that I am getting duplicate posts in the returned results because sometimes a post has multiple likes or comments or attachments. That is causing problems.

Any thoughts? Is there a better way to get the data that I'm after?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a known issue of `squeel` gem: https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/squeel/issues/374

Just monkey patch the gem in your project (put it for example somewhere into `config/initializers`):

```
module Squeel
  module Adapters
    module ActiveRecord
      module RelationExtensions

        def execute_grouped_calculation(operation, column_name, distinct)
          super
        end

      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks! How does one go about applying "the patch provided by the issue creator"? I put the monkey patch into an initializer and that fixed it for now, but I'm curious if there is a more permanent fix out there.

Comment: Ah, there is no patch! I didn't pay attention that actually issue creator didn't provide a patch. Well, disregard the 'patch' part then, you can go fine with hotfix, and probably keep an eye on (subscribe to) that issue on GitHub.

Comment: Curious what just calling `super` does under the hood.